# Search column for a string that is contained in another column of search terms

Tags: vba, excel, search

UPDATE:

I've done a significant amount of learning surrounding VBA and how to use it. I've come up with the below code, but still run into troubles. I never have the debug messages inside the while loops appear. What issue might this be caused by?

New code:

```
Sub SearchForValues()
'VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
Dim count As Integer, SearchRow As Integer, ItemRow As Integer, CopyRow As Integer, position As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'VARIABLE INITILIZATIONS
SearchRow = 1 'for each item in the search set
ItemRow = 1 'for each item in the data set
CopyRow = 1 'for each item that is copied over
count = 0
position = 0

'MsgBox "The main code is about to start"

'MAIN CODE LOOP
While Worksheets(3).Cells(SearchRow, 1) <> "" 'for each search term
    'MsgBox "We are inside the outside while loop."

    While Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1) <> "" 'for each data item
        'MsgBox "We are inside the inside while loop."

        'does the data item contain the search term?
        position = InStr(Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1), Worksheets(3).Cells(SearchRow, 1))
        If position > 0 Then
            Worksheets(3).Cells(CopyRow, 1).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value 'move the row to the open sheet
            CopyRow = CopyRow + 1
            count = count + 1
        End If

        'try next data set item
        ItemRow = ItemRow + 1
    Wend
    'try next search set item
    SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
Wend

MsgBox "Found " & count & " instances and moved them. Done." 'print out count and final message

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occured."

End Sub
```

I'm trying to write a macro in Excel to assist in sorting a relatively large (~4000 rows) set of data. I've dug through a bunch of examples of VBA macros, but I can't figure out how to combine them exactly to solve this problem.

I have a sheet with ~4000 rows with only 1 column that contains a string that describes how code is traced to different data sets. An example cell would contain "db_schema~#~db_custom_object~#~data_set_name". I'm given a list of data_set_name's in another sheet of this document. The task is then this: find the rows in the 4000 row data set that contain any of the data_set_name's from the second sheet.

More simply put (I think), I need to create a macro that searches through an excel sheet using a list of search terms. Ideally, it would copy each row from the original data set that matched the search criteria into a third and empty sheet.

Here is some code that I've gotten offline as a starter. I'm going to keep at it but any solid input would be appreciated.

```
Sub SearchForString()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 4
LSearchRow = 1

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 1

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

  'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
  If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then

     'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
     Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy

     'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
     Sheets("Output").Select
     Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

     'Move counter to next row
     LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

     'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
     Sheets("Data").Select

  End If

  LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

(There are questions -- Start search in row 4?)

I think this approach will help you:

```
Sub SearchForString()
  Dim LSearchRow$, LCopyToRow&, s1$
  On Error GoTo Err_Execute
  'Start search in row 4
  LSearchRow = 1
  'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
  LCopyToRow = 1
  s1 = CStr(LSearchRow)
  While Cells(LSearchRow, 1) <> ""
    'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
    If Cells(LSearchRow, 5) = "Mail Box" Then
     ' copy
      Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(LSearchRow).Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(LCopyToRow)
     'Move counter to next row
      LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
    End If
  LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
  Wend
  'Position on cell A3
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Range("A3").Select
  MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That code was taken completely from another post so I don't claim to understand it. If you look at my above code, it's largely like this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, here is the code solution that I ended up using. It's a simple loop that goes through each search term, then searches the data items using InStr, which returns the position of the substring within the string. If pos > 0, you know the substring is actually contained in the string.

I have it print out the output on the third page of the workbook.

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
'VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
Dim count As Integer, SearchRow As Integer, ItemRow As Integer, CopyRow As Integer, position As Integer
Dim SearchCount As Integer, ItemCount As Long
Dim str() As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'VARIABLE INITILIZATIONS
SearchRow = 1 'for each item in the search set
ItemRow = 1 'for each item in the data set
CopyRow = 1 'for each item that is copied over
SearchCount = 0 'number of search terms
ItemCount = 0 'number of items iterated through
count = 0
position = 0

'MAIN CODE LOOP
Do While Worksheets(2).Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value <> "" 'for each search term
    SearchCount = SearchCount + 1
    ItemRow = 1

    Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1).Value <> "" 'for each data item
        ItemCount = ItemCount + 1

        position = InStr(Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1), Worksheets(2).Cells(SearchRow, 1)) 'does the data item contain the search term?
        If position > 0 Then
            str = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1).Value, "use_your_own_delimiter") 'split the data item into group and object names
            Worksheets(3).Cells(CopyRow, 1).Value = Worksheets(2).Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value
            Worksheets(3).Cells(CopyRow, 2).Value = str(0)
            Worksheets(3).Cells(CopyRow, 3).Value = str(1)
            Worksheets(3).Cells(CopyRow, 4).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(ItemRow, 1).Value 'move the row to the open sheet
            CopyRow = CopyRow + 1
            count = count + 1
        End If

        ItemRow = ItemRow + 1 'try next data set item
    Loop

    SearchRow = SearchRow + 1 'try next search set item
Loop

MsgBox "Searched " & SearchCount & " terms among " & ItemCount & " data entries." & vbNewLine & "Found " & count & " instances and moved them. Done." 'print out count and final message

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occured."

End Sub
```